# I tried to use Gemini Pro in my Python project, but it raises permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I used Gemini Pro example code provided in GCP documentation (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/send-chat-prompts-gemini), but I encountered these errors:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 173, in error_remapped_callable
    return _StreamingResponseIterator(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 95, in __init__
    self._stored_first_result = next(self._wrapped)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 540, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 966, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/my-gemini-pro-project/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-pro' (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.206.202:443 {grpc_message:"Permission \'aiplatform.endpoints.predict\' denied on resource \'//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/my-gemini-pro-project/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-pro\' (or it may not exist).", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2024-01-24T00:41:40.8916329+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codes\gemini_example.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(get_chat_response(chat, prompt))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\codes\gemini_example.py", line 13, in get_chat_response
    response = chat.send_message(prompt)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 709, in send_message
    return self._send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 796, in _send_message
    response = self._model._generate_content(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 437, in _generate_content
    stream = self._prediction_client.stream_generate_content(request=request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform_v1beta1\services\prediction_service\client.py", line 1634, in stream_generate_content
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 177, in error_remapped_callable     
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/my-gemini-pro-project/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-pro' (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "resource"
  value: "projects/my-gemini-pro-project/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-pro"
}
metadata {
  key: "permission"
  value: "aiplatform.endpoints.predict"
}
]
```

- Python version: 3.11
- OS version: Windows 11
- `vertexai` module version: latest

I already added `aiplatform.endpoints.predict` permission to all of my GCP IAM accounts, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how did you run the sample Python program? i.e running in local development machine as python program or using GCP cloud shell? Or in a GCE VM? The issue is likely caused by authentication/authorization issue. Most of GCP API (through SDK) requires IAM account (either user or service account) auth. Which account did you use to run the Python program? If you run locally, you can use Application Default Credentials (ADC) to authenticate. Check this doc https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/sdk-for-gemini/gemini-sdk-overview#authenticate-vertex-python-sdk